# Flutter Module on android native not show icons

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm add flutter module to android native but it not show icon, please to see my code, Where do I have to fix?

**- main.dart** (simple project for create)

**Android function startActivity fullter** (Kotlin)

```
fun handlePage1(v: View) {
        println("PAGE 1")
        // Start executing Dart code to pre-warm the FlutterEngine..
        flutterEngine = FlutterEngine(this);
        flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().executeDartEntrypoint(
            DartExecutor.DartEntrypoint("main.dart", "main")
        );

        // Cache the FlutterEngine to be used by FlutterActivity.
        FlutterEngineCache
            .getInstance()
            .put("engin_main", flutterEngine);

        startActivity(
            FlutterActivity
                .withCachedEngine("engin_main")
                .build(this)
        )
    }
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapplication">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**styles.xml** (LaunchTheme)

```
 <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <!-- Show a splash screen on the activity. Automatically removed when
             Flutter draws its first frame -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
    </style>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi! Were you able to fix this? Can you help me at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66612383/flutter-showing-blank-cross-x-icons